# How to search value for a condition inside an array

Tags: php, arrays

Given array:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [Footer] => Array
                (
                    [id] => 1
                    [field] => about
                    [fvalue] => 
We dream to change our country. nmnmn



                )

        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [Footer] => Array
                (
                    [id] => 2
                    [field] => contact
                    [fvalue] => 


                <h2>Our Contacts</h2>

                <address class="margin-bottom-40">

                    Shekertek, Road: #3 <br>

                    Dhaka, Bangladesh<br>

                    Phone: 01673050495<br>

                    Email: <a href="jegeachi24@gmail.com">jegeachi24@gmail.com</a><br>

                    Skype: <a href="skype:jegeachi.support">jegeachi.support</a>

                </address>





                )

        )

)
```

here is two elements. Elements may be 10 or more. I want to get value of 'fvalue' index inside this array for a given value of 'field' index. For example, if i give 'about'  to this array it will give me 'We dream to change our country. nmnmn'  How can I do this.

Comment: Have you tried anything? Something like `foreach` loop?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have two options for you:

```
$searchField = 'about';
$key = array_search($searchField, array_column(array_column($arr, 'Footer'), 'field'));
echo $arr[$key]['Footer']['fvalue'];
```

OR

```
$searchField = 'about';
$result = array_filter(array_column($arr, 'Footer'), function($arr) use($searchField){return $arr['field'] == $searchField;});
echo $result[0]['fvalue'];
```

Answer (score 0):

you can achieve same thing using simple foreach loop, wrap this within function and use anywhere you want.

```
foreach ($yourArray as => $value) {
    if( $value['footer']['field'] ==  'about'){
        echo $value['footer']['fvalue'];
    }
}
```

within function you can do

```
function getFvalue($yourArray,$fvalue){
    foreach ($yourArray as $value) {
        if( $value['footer']['field'] ==  $fvalue){
            return $value['footer']['fvalue'];
        }
    }   
}
```

Hope this will help you.